# (UWP) How to make the password reveal button always visible and make it work always in a PasswordBox

Tags: xaml, uwp, passwordbox

I am using a PasswordBox in my UWP application where I want to show the password reveal button always. Also, when pressed it should work as expected and should show the passord.

I have modified this default style of the PasswordBox control to set the visibility of Password Reveal button to true. It works and the button is always visible now. But the problem is the password reveal functionality only works when the password is cleared and typed from starting.

```
<Style x:Key="PasswordBoxStyle" TargetType="PasswordBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="PasswordBox">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="RevealButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBorderThemeBrush}"
                                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                    Background="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                               To="0"
                                               Duration="0" />
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                  Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackMediumBrush}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  FontStyle="Normal"
                                  FontSize="16"
                                  Text="&#xE052;"
                                  FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RevealButton"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Opacity="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundRestOpacity}"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                            x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                            Margin="0,0,0,8"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                            FontWeight="Normal" />
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                        HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                        VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                        IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                        IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        IsTabStop="False"
                        ZoomMode="Disabled"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        IsTabStop="False"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                        <Button x:Name="RevealButton"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Style="{StaticResource RevealButtonStyle}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                  IsTabStop="False"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Visibility="Visible"
                  FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  MinWidth="34" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Please notice that I have changed below style for Reveal Password button to have the visibility set to true (it is collapsed by default):

```
<Button x:Name="RevealButton"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Style="{StaticResource RevealButtonStyle}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                  IsTabStop="False"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Visibility="Visible"
                  FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  MinWidth="34" />
```

Comment: "But the problem is the password reveal functionality only works when the password is cleared and typed from starting." I can't reproduce this issue, can you please provide more details?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT did you try with the style I posted in the question? I am facing this issue where the password reveal button is always visible as a result of the modified style (I set visibility to Visible for RevealButton), but when I press the button it does not reveal the password. It only reveals it, when I start typing the password from the beginning. Suppose if I type something in my PasswordBox and move the focus away from it and then back and start typing again, the password reveal does not work anymore.

Comment: Yes, I used your style, the button is always visible, but after making it lost focus, I can reproduce your problem now. I'm investigating on this issue now, as soon as I get the solution, I will post the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design, you can refer to [PasswordBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280219.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#password_character):

> The password reveal button is shown only when the PasswordBox receives focus for the first time and a character is entered. If the PasswordBox loses focus and then regains focus, the reveal button is not shown again unless the password is cleared and character entry starts over.

By default it behaves like so, even you make the `RevealButton` visible always, the problem now is this `Button` doesn't work properly.

The official recommended method is to create a similar UI for example a `CheckBox` to let a user switch the reveal mode. I've also noticed that you changed the default `ToggleButton` to `Button` in the style, if you insist to use this `Button` for switching the reveal mode, you can for example code in behind like this:

```cs
public Page21()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += Page21_Loaded;
}

private Button RevealButton;

private void Page21_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RevealButton = FindChildOfType<Button>(passwordbox);
    RevealButton.Tapped += RevealButton_Tapped;
    RevealButton.ClickMode = ClickMode.Press;
    RevealButton.Click += RevealButton_Click;
    RevealButton.RightTapped += RevealButton_RightTapped;
}

private void RevealButton_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("RevealButton_RightTapped");
    passwordbox.PasswordRevealMode = PasswordRevealMode.Hidden;
}

private void RevealButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("RevealButton_Tapped");
    passwordbox.PasswordRevealMode = PasswordRevealMode.Hidden;
}

private void RevealButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("RevealButton_Click");
    passwordbox.PasswordRevealMode = PasswordRevealMode.Visible;
}

public static T FindChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
{
    var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
    queue.Enqueue(root);
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        DependencyObject current = queue.Dequeue();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
            var typedChild = child as T;
            if (typedChild != null)
            {
                return typedChild;
            }
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The basic idea here is firstly get the `RevealButton` inside the `PasswordBox`, then change the `ClickMode` of `RevealButton` so will the `Click` event be fired when the `Button` is being pressed, by default the `Tapped`/ `RightTapped` event of `Button` will be fired when the pointer is released, finally you can change the `PasswordRevealMode` in these two events. Tapped event works fine on PC, but on mobile, I used `RightTapped` for the point released of `Button`.

Comment: Thanks, I would try it out. Another work around I found out was to use both PasswordBox and TextBox and switch the visibility of these two on pressing show/reveal password button. I tried that and that seems a workable solution to me in the given situation. However, thanks a ton for spending time and finding this work around for me. I will see which one works better for me.

Comment: @AshishAgrawal, OK, look forward to your test result. ;)

Comment: I ended up taking your solution :) if possible please take a look at another issue I am facing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571369/horizontalalignment-stretch-does-not-work-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

You can make the button always be visible by simply finding the button and setting its visibility to `Visibility.Visible`. I assume the button in the default template uses `TemplateBinding` and its visibility is not programmatically toggled because setting its visibility directly would break any existing bindings, such as the aforementioned.

I use the following extension method to find the button:

```
public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject Object) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (Object == null)
        return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(Object); i++)
    {
        var Child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Object, i);
        var Result = (Child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(Child);
        if (Result != null) return Result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then, when the `PasswordBox` loads, do this:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var RevealButton = (sender as PasswordBox).GetChildOfType<Button>();

    if (RevealButton != null)
        RevealButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

You can define a generic `ContentControl` class to subclass `PasswordBox`, if you wish; otherwise, just attach the above `Loaded` event to each instance.

There's a drawback, though: After losing focus, the button no longer has the ability to toggle the visibility of the password despite being visible. It is unclear why.